# What could be a polite alternative to "shove"?

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I want to convey something like "they don't shove it (the message), it's generally subtle".

What I considered replacing it with these, but they don't seem much suitable :

1. rub it in your face
2. thrust / push it on to you

What should I use to keep the statement polite yet emphatic?

Comment: Just so you are aware, 'shove' doesn't really mean anything like 'rub it in your face' other than metaphorically for 'push it on you'. Yes, 'shove' could be used but it would only be understood that way in context.

Comment: In British English 'shove it' would not be used like that in this context.  A British person might say 'shove it in your face' with that meaning but not 'shove it'. 'Shove it' has the specific meaning of "Keep it, I'm not interested" but in a very offensive way. It's actually a shortened form of "You can shove it up your a**e!"

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for "nudge".

Comment: @Mitch Yes I know they are different, but it somewhat suited the context I wanted to use in. Or may be not. I couldn't remember a more relevant term, just put it to make the context more clear.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes I know about the ass thing, just didn't want to use it explicitly as I assumed it would be obvious.

Comment: @HotLicks to nudge is actually being subtle, I wanted two terms to refer methods that juxtapose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few candidates, including: *belabour,* *overstress*, and *overemphasize*, whose  meanings are easily found in dictionaries.

Of these three I favour

> *belabour* = "to explain something more than necessary"
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/belabour)

The word has none of the negative connotations that might be associated with the prefix *over-* and is a neutral and inoffensive description of a way of saying too much about a theme.

Having written a brief answer, I will not belabour the point.

Comment: +1 (but 'over-' is redundant. 'stress' and 'emphasize' already imply 'more than usual'.

Comment: Wonderful. That exactly fits the context. Thanks :)